# Unique values from dataframe columns via loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is it possible to get unique values from multiple columns? I would like each column to have it's own unique values output via a loop.

```
df["col A"].unique()
```

| Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 312 |
| 4 | 6456 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |

**Output**

Col A:
3,
4,
1

Col B:
6456,
312,
4

Comment: Based of the example data you gave us, could you tell us what is the expected output? This way we can understand your specific problem, since it seems that `.unique()` does exactly what you want.

Comment: If you want some kind of vectorized implementation of unique to all the columns of the df at once you could use `df.apply(lambda col: col.unique())` but I'm not sure if it will work because each columns probably will have an output of different length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It kinda depends on what you want as output. You can do it like this to get a dict with each column:

```py
unique_vals = {col:df[col].unique() for col in df}
```

But you probably don't want it as a dataframe like this, because there is no guarantee the amount of unique values is the same for each column.

If you only want to print it it's as simple as:

```py
for col in df:
    print(f'{col}: {df[col].unique()}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `list comprehension`:

```
cola, colb = [df[i].unique() for i in df]
```

or

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.unique())
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
out = pd.DataFrame(map(set,df.values.T.tolist())).T
Out[161]: 
   0     1
0  1   312
1  3  6456
2  4     4
```